# UIStoryboard keeping old outdated references

Tags: ios, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

In my iPad app that uses a UIStoryboard I used to have `UITabBarController` with a couple tabs and icons. Since then I have refactored my app to not use the `UITabBarController` (deleting the view controller in the storyboard. However, when I run my app I get the following error:

`Could not load the "3dicon26better.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.xxxxx.yyyyyyy"`

The icon in question was used as the tab bar icon in the old `UITabBarController`. Apparently my storyboard is keeping references to old deleted view controllers. Is there any way to clear them out?

Comment: Could you check if clean build solves it?

Comment: I tried cleaning the project with no luck.

Comment: Also have you tried deleting the app off the device/simulator and then re-installing it? - There are sometimes issues with resources not being "pushed" to the app.

Comment: I have. Still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have a great solution, but I was able to stop the error by using a process I found in another SO post (can't remember where I found it).

Open my Storyboard in textedit. Search for references to the image in question. Comment them out XML style.

This stopped the errors, but it bothers me that my Storyboard has so many extra dead references in it. :/